# Node.js form submission async error feedback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, asynchronous

Async functionality makes Node.js really powerful and fast. But let's say you are making a web application with something like Express and you have a form for your visitors to fill out. When the form is submitted, it emails the data to someone and also saves the data into a database.

Now with Node, my first instinct would be to do something like this (pseudo code):

```
sendEmailToSomeone(data, function(err, success){
  if (err) { ... }
  // email sent successfully
});

insertIntoDatabase(data, function(err, success){
  if (err) { ... }
  // successful database insertion
});

res.redirect('/thank-you'); // Redirect user to "Thank you" page
```

So you have 2 async functions that happen at the same time, the email is sent and data is put into the database. And the visitor is redirected to some sort of "Thank you for your form submission" page while those things happen on the server. This takes advantage of Node.js async abilities.

But what do you do if one of those 2 async functions get an error? Maybe the email send fails or the database server is offline? How do you get that error feedback to the visitor since they've already been redirected?

Do you use Promises or something and force the visitor to wait for both async functions to finish before giving them the "Thank you" message or "Error Submitting Form" message? If you do this kind of approach, then you kind of lose the async advantages of using Node.js in the first place and you are essentially emulating a PHP type of response.

What is the best approach?

Comment: I personally use Promises everywhere. In your case I would then just use the function [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and when both promises are finished you can send the response. If an error happens then you are in the catch part where you can then do whatever you like

Comment: How do you "lose the async advantages of using Node.js" in that case? Non-blocking I/O does not mean that individual operations are processed faster. It just means that I/O operations won't block the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

All possible answer will have a bias somehow so i explain mine, Since far i have seen, mostly, is controlling the async code execution with a proper library such as [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async#seq) or [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). Particularly Async.seq can help you in an elegant way. Example from library:

```
// Requires lodash (or underscore), express3 and dresende's orm2.
// Part of an app, that fetches cats of the logged user.
// This example uses `seq` function to avoid overnesting and error
// handling clutter.
app.get('/cats', function(request, response) {
  var User = request.models.User;
  async.seq(
    _.bind(User.get, User),  // 'User.get' has signature (id, callback(err, data))
    function(user, fn) {
      user.getCats(fn);      // 'getCats' has signature (callback(err, data))
    }
  )(req.session.user_id, function (err, cats) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      response.json({ status: 'error', message: err.message });
    } else {
      response.json({ status: 'ok', message: 'Cats found', data: cats });
    }
  });
});
```

But you may find this simple & not shiny enough or not proper. Then you can use [Promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise).  In your scenario Promise.All would be nice. Example from library:

```
Promise.all([Promise.resolve('a'), 'b', Promise.resolve('c')])
  .then(function (res) {
    assert(res[0] === 'a')
    assert(res[1] === 'b')
    assert(res[2] === 'c')
  })
```